# Geneate a random integer or to predefined int

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working with some data that for a specific column can only formatted in 1 of three ways:

1. 3884932039484 (this is randomly generated from my program)
2. 0 (this is static and will never change)
3. -1 (this is static and will never change)

I want the program to randomly pick between option 1,2 or 3 and insert one of three options.  This is what I currently have:

```
file = open(r'I:\PythonDataFiles\StandardFeedInput\standardfeed_test.tsv', 'r')
all_lines = file.readlines()
#date_time_answer = input('Please input a date and time(2015-09-15 00:00:00): ')
#if date_time_answer == '':
date_time_answer = '{:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'.format(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days = 1))
date_time = 1  
is_imp = 16  
person_id = 19
aid = 44  
line_id = 49
cid = 50
is_click = 60
app_id = 0
prev_app_id = ''
new_file = open(r'I:\PythonDataFiles\Standard Feed Output\test2.txt', 'w')
for line in all_lines:
    row = line.split('\t')
    row[date_time] = date_time_answer
    row[person_id] = str((random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)), 0, -1)
    if row[app_id] == str(prev_app_id):
        row[is_imp] = str(0)
        row[is_click] = str(1)
    else:
        row[is_imp] = str(1)
    prev_app_id = app_id
    print(row)
    new_file.write('\t'.join(row))
```

Comment: Thank you for including the code and your requirements; what's your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) to pick one of the three options:

```
random.choice([random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999), 0, -1])
```